# How to embed a model object within another model object

Tags: object, backbone.js, set, backbone-model

I am trying to create a model object which contains another model object using the following code

```
//create a question object to be embedded
question = new Onethingaday.Models.Question()
question.set({id:"123456"},{text:"xxxx"},{slug:"xxxx"})

//create the main muse object which contains the question object
muse = new Onethingaday.Models.Muse()
muse.set({question:question.toJSON()})
```

The muse model structure I expect to receive is as follows:

[image]

However, I am getting the following structure instead

[image]

I seem to be getting another layer of 'question:object' as compared to the expected result.

How can I set the objects so that I get the expected result? Or do I need to manipulate the result to remove the additional layer?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this doesn't do what you think it does:

```
question.set({id:"123456"},{text:"xxxx"},{slug:"xxxx"})
```

That sets `id` to `"123456"`, treats as `{text:"xxxx"}` as the options to [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set), and ignores `{slug:"xxxx"}`. You want to say this:

```
question.set({
    id:   "123456",
    text: "xxxx",
    slug: "xxxx"
});
```

to set the three attributes.

On to the real problem. The [default `toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-33) is simply this:

```
return _.clone(this.attributes);
```

so you must be using something that alters `toJSON` to include the `question` key rather than simply returning the attributes object. You can try this with the stock Backbone:

```
var M1 = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var M2 = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var m1 = new M1;
m1.set({ a: 'b', c: 'd' });

var m2 = new M2;
m2.set({ m1: m1.toJSON() });

console.log(m2.attributes);
```

and you'll see this in the console:

```
m1: Object
    a: "b"
    c: "d"
```

with no extra namespacing in sight. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9ptgq/

So you or some library that you're using has altered `toJSON` and you have to take that into account:​

```
var muse = new Onethingaday.Models.Muse()
muse.set(question.toJSON());
```

You can have a look at what `console.log(question.toJSON())` has to say to verify that `toJSON` is at fault.